# Explanation of single-burn trajectories from Lunar surface to Earth surface

Tags: orbital-mechanics, trajectory, sample-return, soviet-union

I learned of the fine book *Soviet Robots in the Solar System* from this excellent [answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/36078/6944).  One chapter in it describes how the Soviets had extreme mass limitations on their lunar sample return vehicle that were overcome when

> a scientist found a small set of flight trajectories for launches from
>   the surface of the Moon that did not require midcourse corrections.

These trajectories allowed a small, relatively simple vehicle with no active navigation to lift off from the Moon with a single burn and reach the surface of the Earth!

The book describes the trajectories in general terms (particularly their limitations), but I'd like to learn more about them.  Searching has not turned up much.

Is there more information available on these trajectories?

Comment: I think Belbruno did some work on this in 1990 or 1991, but Google didn’t find it. I’ll try to get locate some paper papers.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From https://old.math.tsu.ru/50gagarin/moon.doc

> ...перелеты в рамках проекта США Аполлон (1968-1972), а также проекта СССР автоматической экспедиции по забору и возврату Лунного грунта (Луна-16, 20, 24, 1970-1976), они имели близкие траектории, лишь полеты советских КА с Луны на Землю удалось осуществить без коррекции траектории.

translation -

> ...flights within the project of the USA Apollo (1968-1972) and also the project of the USSR of an automatic expedition on a fence and return of Lunar soil (the Luna-16, 20, 24, 1970-1976), they had **close trajectories**, only flights of the Soviet spacecrafts from the Moon to Earth **managed to be made without correction** of a trajectory.

From http://epizodsspace.airbase.ru/bibl/znan/1979/1/1-ka.html

> Старт «Лунной ракеты» к Земле происходил по направлению лунной местной
>   вертикали. Это направление «запоминалось» системой управления при
>   посадке на Луну. В случае если продольная ось взлетной ступени могла
>   быть отклонена от вертикали при взлете, система управления выдавала
>   необходимые команды, благодаря которым ракета выходила на нужную
>   траекторию.
>    При достижении необходимой скорости разгона (например, у АС «Луна-16»
>   она равнялась 2708 м/с) двигатель отключался, и «Лунная ракета» далее
>   шла по баллистической траектории.

transaltion -

> The start of "A lunar rocket" to Earth happened in the direction of a
>   lunar local vertical. This direction "was remembered" by a control
>   system at moonfall. In case the longitudinal axis of a take-off
>   stage(step) could be rejected from a vertical at take-off, the control
>   system issued necessary commands thanks to which the rocket came to
>   the necessary trajectory.
>
> At achievement of necessary speed of dispersal the engine was
>   switched-off, and "The lunar rocket" went further on a ballistic
>   trajectory.

From  http://galspace.spb.ru/index90.file/luna16.html

> После забора грунта и определения лунной вертикали в заданное время возвратная ракета стартовала с поверхности Луны строго вертикально (допустимое первоначальное отклонение продольной оси аппарата от лунной вертикали не должно было превышать 25°). В процессе работы двигателя строго выдерживалось направление вектора скорости по лунной вертикали. Отсечка двигателя производилась при достижении заданной скорости(2700 м/с) в направлении местной вертикали. После окончания работы ДУ отделялась. Весь обратный перелет до Земли возвратная ракета проводила в неориентируемом состоянии с закруткой вокруг любой из осей для равномерного прогрева аппарата от Солнца. Перелет по трассе Луна-Земля, длившийся 84 часа, проходил без коррекций траектории движения ВР.

translation -

> After an intake of soil and definition of a lunar vertical in the set
>   time the returnable rocket started with the surface of the Moon
>   strictly vertically (the admissible initial deviation of a
>   longitudinal axis of the device from a lunar vertical should not have
>   exceeded 25 °). In the course of operation of the engine the direction
>   of a vector of speed on a lunar vertical was strictly maintained. The
>   cut-off of the engine was made at achievement of the set speed (2700
>   m/s) in the direction of a local vertical. After completion of work
>   the propulsion system separated. The returnable rocket carried out all
>   flight to Earth in a nonorientable state with turning around any of
>   axes for uniform warming up of the device from the Sun. The flight
>   lasting 84 hours took place without corrections of a trajectory of the
>   movement of a returnable rocket.

There is also a mention of a scientific article, but this article is not available online.
Авербух А.И., Волохов Ю.Д., Королева Л.С. Методика прицеливания при перелете с Луны на Землю // Космические исследования, 1973, том 11, страницы 407-416.

Averbukh A.I., Volokhov Yu.D., Koroleva L.S. Methods of aiming at flight from the Moon to Earth//Space researches, 1973, volume 11, page 407-416.

Comment: I love that it's the way a ten-year-old would expect to be able to fly back to earth, but the physics checks out and the engineers found a way to make it work.