# Can we launch from the moon?

Tags: launch, the-moon, technology, launchpad, liftoff

Would it be possible with currently rocket technology or technology towards the end of its development (ex. SLS, Starship, New Glenn, etc.) to launch from the moon. Of course, we would send down a crew to set up a launch site, mine for fuel, build the rockets, and control them. We would also send all of the necessary materials. Is this theoretically possible? So, can we launch from the moon?

Comment: At this point? No. No one on Earth has any experience building spaceworthy rockets without a planetwide technological civilization just outside the door to give all the helping hands necessary, much less doing so in a 1/6 gee vacuum environment where we've never had to keep any people alive longer than two weeks.

Comment: Editing your question to invalidate an answer that was already posted? Negative style points.

Comment: Undid the edit. @OrganicMarble

Comment: Note very well: There is only one Moon (initial caps) in the entire universe, so when you use "the" as a qualifier, even when you have moon spelled in lower case, you are implying the Moon.

Comment: I know. Its not an accident. @DavidHammen

Comment: Then it is unclear what you are asking. We have launched from the Moon, and even from some asteroids. Are you asking about in-situ resource utilization (ISRU)? We even have an [tag:ISRU] tag. Look at those related questions if that is what you are asking about. ISRU remains completely hypothetical at this point in time (but there are plans).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, we have already launched from the Moon.

The Soviets did too. [Explanation of single-burn trajectories from Lunar surface to Earth surface](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/36677/explanation-of-single-burn-trajectories-from-lunar-surface-to-earth-surface)

Comment: I mean launch from the moon another planetry body (not Earth or the Moon)@Organic Marble

Comment: @Starshipisgoforlaunch Absolutely nothing in the original version of your question had suggested that what you were asking was in the context of a moon of a celestial body other than Earth and the Moon. A specific term "_the Moon"_ refers to our planet's only natural satellite, while "_a moon_" is a generic term for any planet's natural satellite, and was what you were looking for. {continues}

Comment: @Starshipisgoforlaunch But it is frowned upon to [modify already answered questions in a way that invalidates existing answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions), so maybe rollback this one, and for a launch from a generic moon instead, maybe ask a new separate question? Cheers.

Comment: My orginal questionwas the current version. Upon seeing this answer, I realized that it was unclear,. and clifified it @user47149

Comment: @Starshipisgoforlaunch That's too bad, then. But relax, this particular answer's length and content highly suggests that it had not taken any more than about 60 seconds to fully compose, so no harm had been done, I guess.

Comment: I rollbacked it and am asked the other question seperatly @user47149

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/136156/discussion-between-starship-is-go-for-launch-and-user47149).