# Could we launch from the moon to another planetary body?

Tags: launch, the-moon, technology, launchpad, liftoff

Would it be possible with currently rocket technology or technology towards the end of its development (ex. SLS, Starship, New Glenn, etc.) to launch from the moon. Of course, we would send down a crew to set up a launch site, mine for fuel, build the rockets, and control them. We would also send all of the necessary materials. I mean launch from the moon another planetary body (not Earth or the Moon). Is this theoretically possible? So, can we launch from the moon?

Comment: I don't see an actual question here. If you are asking if one of those rockets could launch a payload from the moon to another planet then the answer is an obvious yes and this question is pointless. If you're asking something else please clarify.

Comment: This also appears to be a duplicate of another question you very recently asked, which has an answer. What is the point of asking this again?

Comment: @GdD: In the other question, people understood just launching from _the_ Moon (our moon). After Organic Marble answered the question in this spirit, it was clarified that OP meant _other_ moons than ours and OP was asked to create a new question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer exactly as asked:

Yes, it is possible to launch from the moon. As mentioned in a comment above, it was [answered](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/59144/47001) recently, showing we already have.

Since we can already go from the surface to orbit, given enough fuel, it should be possible to go further, say Mars. ([Starship](https://www.spacex.com/updates/#starship-moon-announcement) will need to launch from the lunar surface too)

The intent behind the question seems to be: to ask whether it is possible to consider the moon as a gas station, for further deep space missions. You can find several articals such as [this one](https://blog.jatan.space/p/the-moon-as-a-rocket-platform?s=r) stating that it is possible.

However the net benefits of doing so depend on how easily (and regularly) we can source, process and store the fuel on lunar surface. Until we have such a well-oiled base on the moon, it would (probably) be easier to use the lunar gateway as, well, a gateway.

> -will serve as a multi-purpose outpost orbiting the Moon that provides essential support for long-term human return to the lunar
> surface and serves as a staging points for deep space exploration.
> [Gateway | NASA](https://www.nasa.gov/gateway)

Comment: "However the net benefits of doing so depend on how easily (and regularly) we can source, process and store the fuel on lunar surface.": even assuming propellant can cheaply be manufactured on the surface, it requires the moon itself have something that's needed elsewhere. If your ultimate destination is Mars, starting from LEO, just landing on the moon will take more propellant than going directly to Mars.

Comment: And if you're exporting propellant itself, the lunar propellant doesn't need to be cheaper on the moon, it needs to be cheaper in LEO (or wherever you're shipping it to), which means burning most of the propellant to make the delivery.